# Flutter Provider is repainting but not clearing the latest paint

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying Flutter with [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). My goal is simple: I want to use a `StreamProvider` to emit a new integer every second and print this integer. I am not interested in achieving this goal in any other way because I want to specifically learn how to work with the the `StreamProvider`.

The problem is that, even though on every second a new value is printed, the previous state is not cleared, so the numbers are superposing themselves.

How can I solve this?

Source code and screenshot:

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:spellcharger/theme/dark.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Stream<int> timedCounter(Duration interval, [int maxCount]) async* {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(interval);
      yield i++;
      if (i == maxCount) break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider.value(
      value: timedCounter(new Duration(seconds: 1), 2000),
      initialData: 0,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: darkTheme,
        home: CounterWrapper()  // LoginScreen(title: 'SpellCharger'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<int>(
      builder: (_, a, child) {
        // THIS IS REPAINTING BUT NOT CLEARING THE PREVIOUS PAINT
        return Text(a.toString());
      }
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: it is working completely fine for me as you explain and expected.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya Thank you for taking the time to test it. The problem is that, depending on the size of my Android emulator, it does not refresh properly. The problem had anything to do with Provider =(. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I'm using provider version 4.0.5 and it working fine.

*Note: I remove theme spellcharger because I don't have it.*

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to test my code. That was helpful.  I figured out the problem was that my emulator is not refreshing the contents depending on its size. If I make the emulator smaller it updates just fine and the screen gets black as in your example. Thank you again

Comment: I also just realized that having a Scaffold component on the screen fixed the painting problem o.O